# Weird lines with curve modifier

Tags: modifiers

I'm using the curve modified to bend an object on a curve. But for some reason the mesh of the object gets weird lines on the object. I've also tested a simple deform bend modifier and the object just looks smooth. Any idea how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: Try to increase the curve resolution

Comment: @lemon that worked thanks! Do you have any idea how to make the child of the object curve along with it's parent?

Comment: You should indicate how is this child and eventually ask another question about it. Don't see clearly what you mean here.